# binomial test and understand the p-value

Tags: p-value, binomial-distribution

```
> binom.test(15,30,1/2)

    Exact binomial test

data:  15 and 30
number of successes = 15, number of trials = 30, p-value = 1
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3129703 0.6870297
sample estimates:
probability of success 
                   0.5
```

In the above test, the probability of success is 0.5 and I got 15 out of 30, which is exactly 0.5. Why I am seeing the insignificant p-values (1) instead that the results are as expected ?

I know there are multiple questions on this but not exactly about p-value and also I could not comment there as I do not have enough reputations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternative hypothesis is that the true probability of success does not equal 0.5. Your test returns an insignificant p-value of 1, which means you reject the alternative hypothesis. Your null hypothesis that the probability of success equals 0.5 is not disproven by the data, which has an observed probability of success of 0.5 In other words, the results are as "expected" by the null hypothesis.